# Line is not drawn (It seems that pygame.draw.polygon is not running)

Tags: python, pygame

I made Button frame. But Square is not drawn.

```
class button:
    def __init__(self,screen,size): # size -->(width,height)
        self.width = size[0]
        self.height = size[1]
        self.screen = screen
    def Buttongenerate(self,TEXT,POS):
        font = pygame.font.Font(None,self.height//3)
        text = font.render(TEXT,True,(250,250,250))
        textsize = font.size(TEXT)
        TEXTPOS = [self.width+(self.width-textsize[0])/2,\
           self.height+(self.height-textsize[1])/2]
        self.screen.blit(text,TEXTPOS)
        pygame.draw.polygon(self.screen, (250,250,250), [[POS[0],POS[1]],\ 
        [POS[0]+self.width,POS[1]],[POS[0]+self.width,POS[1]+self.height],\ 
        [POS[0],POS[1]+self.height]], 2)


while True:
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    buttontest2 = button(screen,(200,100))
    buttontest2.Buttongenerate("TEST",(200,200))
    pygame.display.flip()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit(0)
```

When I run this code , but It seems that pygame.draw.polygon is not running

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pygame.draw.polygon` works just fine.

Your problem is that you calculate `TEXTPOS` wrong (I just guess the text should be rendered inside the rectangle). You should use

```
TEXTPOS = [POS[0]+(self.width-textsize[0])/2, POS[1]+(self.height-textsize[1])/2]
```

which actually uses `POS` to calculate the final position of the text.

Otherwise, the text is rendered above the rectangle. Here's the full, running code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,600))
class button:
    def __init__(self,screen,size): # size -->(width,height)
        self.width = size[0]
        self.height = size[1]
        self.screen = screen
    def Buttongenerate(self,TEXT,POS):
        font = pygame.font.Font(None,self.height//3)
        text = font.render(TEXT,True,(250,250,250))
        textsize = font.size(TEXT)
        TEXTPOS = [POS[0]+(self.width-textsize[0])/2, POS[1]+(self.height-textsize[1])/2]
        self.screen.blit(text,TEXTPOS)
        pygame.draw.polygon(self.screen, (250,250,250), [[POS[0],POS[1]],[POS[0]+self.width,POS[1]],[POS[0]+self.width,POS[1]+self.height],[POS[0],POS[1]+self.height]], 2)

while True:
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    buttontest2 = button(screen,(200,100))
    buttontest2.Buttongenerate("TEST",(200,200))
    pygame.display.flip()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
```

---

Note that it would be better to create a new surface for the text and rectangle once instead of loading the font, rendering the text, and drawing on the screen surface every iteration of the main loop.